# How to check performance of mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have been learning query optimization, increase query performance and all but in general if we create a query how can we know if this is a wise query.

I know we can see the execution time below, But this time will not give a clear indication without a good amount of data. And usually, when we create a new query we don't have much data to check.

I have learned about clauses and commands performance. But is there is anything by which we can check the performance of the query? Performance here is not execution time, it means that whether a query is **"ok"** or not, without data dependency.

As we cannot create that much data that would be in live database.

Comment: you know.. nothing is perfect in this world.. :) "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: One of the most important things you should have picked up when learning query optimization is that the "right" query is always data-dependent. While query A might perform better than query B on a small dataset it might be the other way round on a large dataset.

Comment: Query optimization is like Art your need  to know some parts of the MySQL engine. The MySQL Query Optimizer can change the query execution plan on changed data always the case with JOINS. MySQL Query Optimizer can access the tables in the `wrong` order note this is not bad when you dont use GOUP BY or ORDER BY. but if you do the chance is MYSQL needs to use an temporary table and an filesort for the correct results slowing down the performance of your query.

Comment: @Devart - how is your commercial product teaching the OP how to learn about query optimization?

Comment: @N.B. it is a tool, it is not a manual. This tool will allow changing query, measuring performance and viewing results simply and quickly. So, it even may teach.

Comment: @Devart - but it's not teaching, the tool is so you can get some profit. Your comment didn't help teach anyone anything so I flagged it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

General performance of a query can be checked using the EXPLAIN command in MySQL. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

It shows you how MySQL engine plans to execute the query and allows you to do some basic sanity checks i.e. if the engine will use keys and indexes to execute the query, see how MySQL will execute the joins (i.e. if foreign keys aren't missing) and many more.

You can find some general tips about how to use EXPLAIN for optimizing queries here (along with some nice samples): http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above, Right query is always `data-dependent`. Up to some level you can use the below methods to check the performance

1. You can use `Explain` to understand the *Query Execution Plan* and that may help you to correct some stuffs.  For more info :
    Refer Documentation [Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)
2. You can use `Query Analyzer`. Refer [MySQL Query Analyzer](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html)

Answer (score 3):

I like to throw [my cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) at Newbies because they often do not understand how important `INDEXes` are, or don't know some of the subtleties.

When experimenting with multiple choices of query/schema, I like to use

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

That counts low level actions, such as "read next record".  It essentially eliminates caching issues, disk speed, etc, and is very reproducible.  Often there is a counter in that output (or multiple counters) that match the number of rows in the table (sometimes +/-1) -- that tells me there are table scan(s).  This is *usually* not as good as if some `INDEX` were being used.  If the query has a `LIMIT`, that value may show up in some Handler.

A really bad query, such as a `CROSS JOIN`, would show a value of N*M, where N and M are the row counts for the two tables.

I used the Handler technique to 'prove' that virtually all published "get me a random row" techniques require a table scan.  Then I could experiment with small tables and Handlers to come up with a list of [faster random routines](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random).

Another tip when timing...  Turn off the Query_cache (or use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`).