# Slow query hangs the server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, yoast

I am getting problem with my website and server guys tells it because of MySQL slow query. My website is in Wordpress CMS. Below is the query, that creates problems. I am not sure, when this query runs. I have more than 70000+ users in my database.

```
# Query_time: 1078.445935  Lock_time: 0.000236 Rows_sent: 59  Rows_examined: 379721873
SET timestamp=1538539120;
SELECT DISTINCT wp_users.ID FROM wp_users LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt1.user_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt2.user_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt3 ON (wp_users.ID = mt3.user_id AND mt3.meta_key = 'wpseo_noindex_author' ) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_users.ID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.post_author FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type IN ( 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'static-block' ) ) AND ( 
  wp_usermeta.meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_profile_updated' 
  AND 
  ( 
    ( mt1.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' AND mt1.meta_value != '0' ) 
    AND 
    ( 
      ( mt2.meta_key = 'wpseo_noindex_author' AND mt2.meta_value != 'on' ) 
      OR 
      mt3.user_id IS NULL
    )
  )
) ORDER BY wp_usermeta.meta_value+0 

DESC;
```

Comment: Try have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117242/how-to-check-performance-of-mysql-query . On a note, in your `WHERE` clause you have the condition `1=1 AND`.... `1=1` will always be true, so it seems rather redundant? What's the reasoning behind this condition? Will it return additional rows? If so, that might be what's slowing down your query. Try to narrow the row selection down to what you wish to retrieve from the database specifically.

Comment: This query created by a yoast plugin by default.

Comment: It's a part of the YOAST WP SEO plugin. Your options are to not use that plugin, or to upgrade your server to better handle the requests.

FYI the server I tested this query on has a 2x Intel Xeon E5-2620v4 @2.1GHz setup and would take 370 seconds to process this query with 70k users.

As far as I can see from the mysql EXPLAIN, there isn't any way to optimise this query further.

Comment: I agree with you ThailerThanYall. So you think, the only way to run this query fast to upgrade the server to better handle this request?

Answer (score 0):

Yoast SEO https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/ plugin issues that SQL query.
It's just not designed for such number of users and it's SQL queries dont expect that.

Cleanest solution of course is to not use that plugin for such websites.

In a case when situation is critical and you cant switch it off - of course there are some hacks possible to workaround that, or modification of code.

It's called from `class-author-sitemap-provider.php` file, get_users method. Right now it passes through all your posts, and queries afterwards for users who ever posted.
You may try to set
`$defaults['has_published_posts'] = true;`
into `false` to at least exclude posts table from query.
Removing `meta_query` parameter would make query even simpler.
But all that is dirty hacks of course which will affect functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have implemented your solution, will check if it resolve our issue.

Comment: And for SEO, which another plugin we can use?

Comment: Answer to that question is really depends on a lot of factors and think can be some separate discussion. For simple SEO functionality like changing meta tags / titles I've successfully used "SEO Ultimate" which is relatively lightweight. Of course the price is that its missing a lot of functions Yoast offers so it's not a universal solution.

Comment: I have the same issue any updates if the provided solution worked? The slow queries generated are exactly the same

Comment: I did some similar profiling of our database with tens of thousands of users and similarly, found excess usermeta being stored on behalf of yoast. By default it adds urls for the 10 social networks for each user (ie. Facebook, Google, Wikipedia ...). We ended up commenting out that section in the plugin and deleting the mostly blank if not all entries in the wp_usermeta table freeing up over 200k rows, however our database is still running over 1 million rows so we're still trying to optimize. It's a hack but I think it'd be nice to have these as optionals or cleanable inside the plugin.